# Arduino IDE won't launch in Windows 8.1

Tags: java, arduino

What I've tried

1 Installing Java SDK and runtime (JDK8 but when extracted it says jdk1.8.0_25)

2 add the %JAVA_HOME%\bin to Path environment variable

3 JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to the jdk folder

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

I see the splash screen for a second on launch then nothing

Still no luck. Can anyone suggest some next steps?

I'm using a custom Arduino build for the Intel Edison available here
https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-23242

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed?  What version of Java is required by the program?  It would be extremely useful if that information as in the question itself.  Additionally. when you say it won't launch, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: JDK8 but when extracted it says jdk1.8.0_25. I see the splash screen for a second on launch then nothing

Comment: @user2005121 Would you mind From a command line, launch arduino.exe with the following command:
arduino.exe --l4j-debug  and post the log file in your post,It might help others to resolve your problem,Thanks

Comment: Is your Windows 32-bit or 64-bit? Which Java are you trying to install, 32-bit or 64-bit? Sometimes this is why Java can't be found by a program, it's looking for the wrong bitness.